# "npm err: Unexpected end of JSON input" when installing express-mysql-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, backend, npm-install

I am working on a nodejs project that authenticates the user using passportjs. I am using mysql for database.
Now i want to implement session storage using "**express-mysql-session**" package.

When I am installing **express-mysql-session** using npm it's showing this error:

```
$ npm install express-mysql-session --save
 npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ies":{"express":"3.3.'

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-22T10_22_41_836Z-debug.log
```

But when I am installing any other packages it's installing it successfully

*This is the **"complete log"** of the run:*

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'express-mysql-session',
1 verbose cli   '--save'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.18.0
4 verbose npm-session 63020bd35662f4f0
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-mysql-session 20ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for express-mysql-session@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ies":{"express":"3.3.'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 367ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ies":{"express":"3.3.'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
12 verbose cwd D:\Projects\AppName
13 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express-mysql-session" "--save"
15 verbose node v12.18.0
16 verbose npm  v6.14.4
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ies":{"express":"3.3.'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

*Here is the **"package.json"** file:*

```
{
    "name": "App Name",
     "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
     "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
     "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
     "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
     "ejs": "^3.1.5",
     "express": "^4.17.1",
     "express-flash": "0.0.2",
     "express-session": "^1.17.2",
     "my-sql": "^1.2.15",
     "mysql": "^2.18.1",
     "passport": "^0.4.1",
     "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    }
}
```

> It isn't working when installing in other projects.

Now what should i do ???

Thanks to everyone who attempts to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly corrupt cache?

```
npm cache clean --force
```